# Fastest way to import text file into database

Tags: c#, database, import

I've a text file containing record of a dump of database table in a custom format, this text have a character in a specific position that identifies the operation with the record :

- M = Insert or Update
- D = Delete Record

Therefore if i find a D record in text file i need to delete record into database, instead if i find an M record i need to Insert the record if not exist in the database, if already exist i need to update it.

What is the better and fastest way to import a similar text file in a database table using .NET Framework and c#?
I have 300000 record of average in this text file.

Thanks

Comment: How many records are there in the database you have to match with?

Comment: Are you using an ORM or are you writing bare SQL statements?

Comment: Can you please qualify what you mean by fastest? i.e., fastest way to code it up, fastest runtime etc.

Comment: In the database table i have an average of 500000 record. I could have 4 different types of database server : MSSQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Firebird connected with ODBC. I would write a code that have a good performance importing this text file.

Comment: Will your file contain duplicate records?  For instance, is it possible that there will be a "D" record, then an "M" record, then another "D" record that all correspond to the same record within your database?  Does the order matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use ADO.NET to create a typed datatable to load the data into and set the datarowstate accordingly, then flush the data via a DataAdapter.

The fastest way is probably creating a bulk SQL-Script to execute. LinQ can save you a lot of time when selecting the data (you can probably transform it on the fly).

There are also platform specific solutions that should be considered. See here a bulk insert for SQLServer.

http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/xun/archive/2008/04/15/sql-bulk-insert-and-ado-net-sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Why not parse the text and generate insert, update and delete statements then just run the script you generated?

Comment: I'd also add in some commits at specific intervals to speed it up.

Comment: How cain i determine if a SQL statements is a Insert or Update ? Do i need to query the destination table for understand if a record already exist or not ?

Comment: @aleroot - Just read your question again. I didn't realize that you use M for insert and update. Since the records are probably all different, maybe do a try catch in the SQL script. If an exception is caught and the error is that the record already exists, do an update in the catch. Not super elegant though.If you can do an IF EXISTS with what ever makes the record unique that would be better but I have a feeling you won't know what the primary key is for each record.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this, you'll have to parse the text no matter what to determine what SQL statement you need to run. You'll have to decide for yourself whether or not it's an update or an insert statement, hopefully you can do batches, otherwise hitting the database every time you hit an "M" so often isn't gonna be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you could take advantage of the [Bulk Insert functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).  That should be the fastest way to insert data from a file into the database.  The first thing I would do is insert the data in your file into a "landing table" (i.e. a table whose structure matches the structure of your file).  Also note: [.NET 2.0 introduced SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx), which would be similarly useful if you already have the data in memory or are reading it with some kind of DataReader.

Once the contents of your file are inserted into your landing table, you can then execute a series of SQL statements to merge your landing table into your target table(s).  Below is an example implementation of those SQL statements (Disclaimer:  I did not check these for correctness):

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM LandingTable
    WHERE
        LandingTable.RecordType = 'D'
        AND LandingTable.KeyField1 = MyTable.KeyField1
        AND LandingTable.KeyField2 = MyTable.KeyField2


UPDATE MyTable SET
    MyTable.Field1 = LandingTable.Field1,
    MyTable.Field2 = LandingTable.Field2,
    -- ...
FROM MyTable
INNER JOIN LandingTable ON
    LandingTable.KeyField1 = MyTable.KeyField1
    AND LandingTable.KeyField2 = MyTable.KeyField2
where
    LandingTable.RecordType = 'U'

INSERT INTO MyTable (
    Field1,
    Field2,
    -- ...
)
SELECT
    LandingTable.Field1,
    LandingTable.Field2,
    -- ...
FROM LandingTable
WHERE
    LandingTable.RecordType = 'I'

-- Consider how to handle "Insert" records where there is already a record in MyTable with the same key
-- Possible solution below: treat as an "Update"
UPDATE MyTable SET
    MyTable.Field1 = LandingTable.Field1,
    MyTable.Field2 = LandingTable.Field2,
    -- ...
FROM MyTable
INNER JOIN LandingTable ON
    LandingTable.KeyField1 = MyTable.KeyField1
    AND LandingTable.KeyField2 = MyTable.KeyField2
where
    LandingTable.RecordType = 'I'

-- Now only insert records from LandingTable where there is no corresponding record in MyTable with the same key (determined with a left outer join)
INSERT INTO MyTable (
    Field1,
    Field2,
    -- ...
)
SELECT
    LandingTable.Field1,
    LandingTable.Field2,
    -- ...
FROM LandingTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable ON
    MyTable.KeyField1 = LandingTable.KeyField1
    AND MyTable.KeyField2 = LandingTable.KeyField2
WHERE
    LandingTable.RecordType = 'I'
    and MyTable.KeyField1 is null
```

Links that I found after doing a quick search:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx
- http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/SqlBulkCopy_in_ADO_NET_2_0.aspx
- http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/xun/archive/2008/04/15/sql-bulk-insert-and-ado-net-sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Comment: Woops!  I notice that the original question mentions using "M" to denote both an insert and update, whereas my code example assumes "I" for insert and "U" for update.  Modifying the example to work with "M" should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

Insert Into Temporary table then JOIN to UPDATE or DELETE.